# Why Vaadin TreeGrid loads the data two times after Scrolling?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have the following issue: When my Treegrid gets loaded for the first time, all the root data where correct added. But when i scroll drown in the TreeGrid, the data are picked up again and added to the Treegrid.

Does anyone know how to deactivate lazy loading in a Treegrid when scrolling?

Here is my Method which created the Treegrid

```
 private Component createCategoriesTree() {
    treeGrid.setHeight("100%");
    treeGrid.addComponentHierarchyColumn(productCategory -> getProductCategoryName(productCategory)).setHeader("Kategorie").setSortable(false);
    ProductCategory root = productCategoriesService.getRootCategory();
    HierarchicalDataProvider dataProvider = new AbstractBackEndHierarchicalDataProvider<ProductCategory, Void>() {
        @Override
        public int getChildCount(HierarchicalQuery<ProductCategory, Void> query) {
        
            if (query.getParent() == null) {
                List<ProductCategory> list = productCategoriesService.findByParentId(root.getId());
                return (int) list.size();
            } else {
                List<ProductCategory> list = productCategoriesService.findByParentId(query.getParent().getId());
                return (int) list.size();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasChildren(ProductCategory item) {
            List<ProductCategory> list = productCategoriesService.findByParentId(item.getId());
            if (list != null && list.size() > 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Stream<ProductCategory> fetchChildrenFromBackEnd(HierarchicalQuery<ProductCategory, Void> query) {
            if (query.getParent() == null) {
                return productCategoriesService.findByParentId(root.getId()).stream();
            } else {
                return productCategoriesService.findByParentId(query.getParent().getId()).stream();
            }
        }
    };
    treeGrid.setDataProvider(dataProvider);
    return treeGrid;
}
```

Comment: Does your `ProductCategory` have a proper equals-and-hashcode?

Comment: Yes! thank you. i think i found the solution i changed the fetchChildrenFromBackEnd() to :
                    return productCategoriesService.findByParentIdOrderByCategoryNameAsc(root.getId()).stream().skip(query.getOffset()).limit(query.getLimit());

The skip and limit method did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was:

missing skip method like following method body:

```
@Override
        protected Stream<ProductCategory> fetchChildrenFromBackEnd(HierarchicalQuery<ProductCategory, Void> query) {
            if (query.getParent() == null) {
                return productCategoriesService.findByParentIdOrderByCategoryNameAsc(root.getId()).stream().skip(query.getOffset()).limit(query.getLimit()); //THIS
            } else {
                return productCategoriesService.findByParentIdOrderByCategoryNameAsc(query.getParent().getId()).stream(); //THIS
            }
        }
```